# Excel Conditional Formatting - Text contained in List?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Another Excel Conditional formatting, haven't been able to find a relevant answer yet.

I have two sheets with data. Sheet2 has simple list of finished items (all in Column B). The Sheet1 has a table of when an item needs to be done according to date - each new column is a date, and the rows underneath have items to be finished. I am hoping to have the items in Sheet1 be colored green once they are added to the finished list in Sheet2. The table in Sheet1 is tied to other spreadsheets, and updates daily, so I need something that is fluid (ie, I can't manually color the cells, as the item to be finished might change dates).

I have gotten this to work for single columns at a time using "=MATCH(B4, 'Sheet2'!B:B)" (for column B on sheet 1, where the items I need formatted begin on row 4). However, I can't enter in this conditional formatting for every column (well, I'd rather not). Is there a way to have every cell in Sheet1B4:Z41 look at Sheet2B:B, detect if that value is in Sheet2, and then be formatted (colored) appropriately?

Let me know if I need to clarify this more, busy day and I'm writing fast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make the lookup range an absolute reference, i.e.

```
=MATCH(B4, 'Sheet2'!$B:$B, 0)
```

Conditional formatting rules also adhere to absolute and relative references so if you apply a rule A1=B1 to a range A1:C3 then C3 will check if C3=D3, in this case C4 checked Sheet2!C:C.

You should also use 0 for good measure unless you know the elements in Sheet2!B:B are ordered and a subset of elements in Sheet1.

Comment: Gah, I knew it had to be something simple I was stupidly missing. Thanks a bunch! (Minor note, I was using 0, just forgot to add it into my question)